# redraw bootstrap datatables with server side processing with new parameters

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, server-side

I am using bootstrap datatables with serverside processing.
My js code will pass parameters to the server and loads the returned JSON data to my table.

**Following is the code that initializes the datatable:**

```
function drawforfirsttime(){
    oTable=$('#example1').dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "db/ServerProcessingTests.php?criteria="+criteria+"&centre="+centre+"&month="+month+"&se="+se+"&count="+count
        });
}
```

The parameters that I am passing (like criteria,centre etc) are the values of dropdowns in my page.
Whenever a dropdown value changes the datatable should be refreshed with new parameter value.

**Following is the code that I use to refresh the table:**

```
$('#centre').change(function(){
    changedata();
});

function changedata(){
    if(oTable!=null){
    oTable.fnDraw(false);
    }else{
        drawforfirsttime();
    }
};
```

First time load is working properly. But whenever I redraw the page new parameters are not sent to the server only the first time parameters are sending.

Please help me how can I send new parameters to the server every time the dropdown value changes.

Answer (score 0):

use this event

```
.on('preXhr.dt', function ( e, settings, data ) {
            data.archive = window.is_archive;

    } );
```

where `window.is_archive` is whatever you want